# How to transpose rows separated with blank (Nan) data to multi-column in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transform

I'm new to python an I want to improve several excel programs I've made using VBA.
Like the one below.
I have a machine log which is consist of 2 Columns and average of 50,000 Rows, every group is separated by spaces.
Sample:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmK9q.jpg)

and i want to transform it to this columnar per group.

[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRF5i.jpg)

I don't need the 1st column, what I only need is the 2nd columns to be transformed.
I already made it thru VBA in excel but it took 2-5 mins to transform 50,000 rows.

I've been self learning python for a while and I hope it will speed up the process thru pandas or numpy.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 50,000 rows of input data or output data?

Comment: More or less its 50,000 rows of input data. Its from a machine log which sometimes we need to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input data:

```
df = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx", header=None, names=["Operation", "Data"])
```

```
>>> df
       Operation                          Data
0    <Operation>                           NaN  # begin 1st group (idx1)
1            NaN  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>
2            NaN            <Type>value</Type>
3            NaN            <Name>value</Name>
4            NaN         <Action>value</Action
5            NaN            <Data>value</Data>
6   </Operation>                           NaN  # end 1st group (idx2)
7    <Operation>                           NaN  # begin 2nd group (idx1)
8            NaN  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>
9            NaN            <Type>value</Type>
10           NaN            <Name>value</Name>
11           NaN         <Action>value</Action
12           NaN            <Data>value</Data>
13  </Operation>                           NaN  # end 2nd group (idx2)
14   <Operation>                           NaN  # begin 3rd group (idx1)
15           NaN  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>
16           NaN            <Type>value</Type>
17           NaN            <Name>value</Name>
18           NaN         <Action>value</Action
19  </Operation>                           NaN  # end 3rd group (idx2)
```

Comments inside the snippet. Below a one-line version of this code:

```
data = []
idx1 = df[df["Operation"].eq("<Operation>")].index  # [0, 6, 13]
idx2 = df[df["Operation"].eq("</Operation>")].index  # [7, 14, 19]

for i1, i2 in zip(idx1, idx2):  # [(0, 7), (6, 14), (13, 19)]
    # Get values inside the group [(1, 6), (7, 13), (14, 18)]
    df1 = df["Data"].loc[i1+1:i2-1].reset_index(drop=True)
    data.append(df1)

# Concatenate all operations, swap columns and rows (.Transpose)
out = pd.concat(data, axis="columns").T.reset_index(drop=True)

# One line
# out = pd.concat([df["Data"].loc[i1+1:i2-1].reset_index(drop=True)
#                      for i1, i2 in zip(df[df["Operation"].eq("<Operation>")].index,
#                                        df[df["Operation"].eq("</Operation>")].index)],
#                 axis="columns").T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
                              0                   1                   2                      3                   4
0  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>  <Type>value</Type>  <Name>value</Name>  <Action>value</Action  <Data>value</Data>
1  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>  <Type>value</Type>  <Name>value</Name>  <Action>value</Action  <Data>value</Data>
2  <Timestamp>value</Timestamp>  <Type>value</Type>  <Name>value</Name>  <Action>value</Action                 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much Corralien, I'll try and i'll get back on you..

Comment: again thank you so much. Apologies, I just tried the code. I can only practice coding during day offs. But anyways, I tested the code and it works. Python managed to transpose the ~57K rows in just ~12 seconds compared to 2-5 mins on excel.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to cast vote. :-)

Comment: But I'll get back to it, but already accepted the answer.