# Transform group of rows separated by "##" to multiple columns. - In Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transform

How to transform a single row separated by string "##" (or any string) into columns.

Apologies, I know this is easy but I'm just new to python.

Sample data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I've tried this but the result is not what I want:
data = []
Idx = df[df["Errors"].eq("##")].index

```
for i in Idx:
    df1 = df["Errors"].iloc[::i+1].reset_index(drop=True)
    data.append(df1)
    out = pd.concat(data, axis="columns").T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Appreciate anyone's help.
Thank you.

Comment: Pandas is not particularly good at handling data with variable-length rows.  Is there a reason you really need pandas for this?  It would be easy to read from file into a list of lists.

Comment: You should also post your sample data as text and not screenshots.  Is the data CSV?  Is it in Excel?  A dataframe already?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm working on a project that transforms machine logs of thousands of rows, I don't really know what is better to use, panda or numpy.

Comment: Unless the data is numeric (which this isn't), I don't know what either `pandas` or `numpy` will buy you.  Maybe if you are computing statistics on the error frequency, that's when you move into `pandas`.

Comment: @sedavidw It is from a machine log with ".LOG as extension. I need to open it in excel first then save as excel format. Then I converted to dataframe and need to display the result to Tkinker tree view.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is not numeric, only strings. I just need to transform it the faster way. I'll already made it thru VBA but it is very slow to transform thousands of rows.

Comment: @KeneXs the point of my comment was to help people reproduce it.  Any code that someones writes to try to help you will be based on assumptions given what you have here. And those assumptions may not be valid.  If you can give raw data in text format, folks will be better set up to help you

Comment: @sedavidw Noted on this. Apologies, I don't have the raw file for now I left may laptop at work. I'll attached as soon as i have it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this non-pandas approach:

```
data = []
row = []
for line in open('x.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "##":
        if row:
            data.append(row)
            row = []
    row.append(line)
if row:
    data.append(row)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[['##', 'ERROR #123 <SHTL>', 'Error1', 'Error1', 'Error1'],
 ['##', 'ERROR #124 <NSOP>', 'Error2', 'Error2', 'Error2'],
 ['##', 'ERROR #124 <NSOP>', 'Error3', 'Error3', 'Error3', 'Error3', 'Error3'],
 ['##', 'ERROR #111 <NSOL>', 'Error4', 'Error4', 'Error4'],
 ['##',
  'ERROR #111 <NSOL>',
  'Error5',
  'Error5',
  'Error5',
  'Error5',
  'Error5',
  'Error5',
  'Error5'],
 ['##', 'ERROR #128 <PBI>', 'Error6', 'Error6', 'Error6', 'Error6']]
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try.

Comment: Sir, I was not able to apply the code, raw from is in .xlsx format. Is there any other if the file is to be imported is in excel..?

Comment: Well, you can use `df.iloc` to iterate through the imported dataframe, instead of using a file, like my example.

Answer (score 0):

For hours of trial and error.

I found this code working.:

```
data = []
Idx1 = df[df["Errors"].eq("##")].index
Idx2 = Idx1[1:] #to know the limit between "##".

for i1, i2 in zip(Idx1, Idx2):
    df1 = df["Errors"].loc[i1+1:i2-1].reset_index(drop=True)
    data.append(df1)
out = pd.concat(data, axis="columns").T.reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
```

This is based on my previous question on thread:
[How to transpose rows separated with blank (Nan) data to multi-column in python/pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717140/how-to-transpose-rows-separated-with-blank-nan-data-to-multi-column-in-python)

Thanks to @Corralien.

But please send me other ways to improve.
Thanks.